# Python: Quadriatic Graph Multiple Numbers Error

Tags: python

I have created a code to print the equation `y=x^2+3`

However it looks like every time I finish it the y axis has multiple numbers, like top to bottom-19,19,19,19,19,17,17,9,7,7,7 etc

What I need is 19,18,17,16,15....0

Also I cant seem to code the xaxis which is 0 to 4

```
##A program to plot the graph of y = x^2 + 3 using formatted output
##
##Graph from x = 0 to x = 4
##We must draw the graph 'backwards' (top down)
##
##label the y-axis
##
print('{0:>{width}}'.format('y', width=2))

##start with x = 4
##calculate y = x^2 + 3
x = 4
y = x**2+3
oldY = y

##in a counted loop
for x in range(4,-1,-1):
##    draw axis value, vert line, space over and place a dot for current x/y value
    print('{0:>3}{1:>{width}}'.format(str(y)+'|','*', width=x*2))

    ##    calculate y = x^2 + 3
    y = x**2+3
    ##    calcuate difference in y from previous y value
    difference = oldY - y
    ##    draw that many axis values and vert lines
    for lines in range(0,difference+1):
        print('{0:>3}'.format(str(y)+'|'))
```

I'd like to have only formatted ouputs and loops.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, you need to draw the graph "backwards": first print the empty lines between the current y and the previous one, then print the current y value. You need to put the "*" print at the end of the outer loop (the loop on x)

Next issue is the number of empty lines. Between 19 and 12, you should only have 6 empty lines, because you don't count the line 19 and the line 12.

```
old=19
new=12
#your code
old-new+1= 8
#actual number of empty lines
old-new-1=6
```

Next, you have repeated numbers in the y axis because you're always printing the same y. Here:

```
for lines in range(0,difference+1):
    print('{0:>3}'.format(str(y)+'|'))
```

The y stays the same, and is equal to the "new" value. You need to decrease y from "old value -1" to "new value +1". Something like `oldY=oldY-1, print(oldY)`.

Finally, you never update `oldY`. At the end of the outer loop, you should have `oldY=y`

Comment: could you explain this in an easier way?

Comment: I m still a beginner and this explanation isn't very easy for me :(

Answer (score 0):

You could also calculate your values of `y` in advance and iterate over all `y` values, inserting markers when a `y` value matches one of your values to plot, as follows:

```
print('{0:>{width}}'.format('y', width=2))

f = lambda x: x**2 + 3

xmax = 4
xs = range(xmax+1)
ys = [f(x) for x in xs]
ymax = max(ys)
xscale = 5
i = len(ys)-1
for y in range(ymax,-1,-1):
    # The y-axis
    print('{0:>3}|'.format(y), end='')
    if i >= 0 and y==ys[i]:
        print('{marker:>{width}}'.format(marker='*', width=xs[i]*xscale))
        i -= 1
    else:
        print()
print('   L' + '_'*len(xs)*xscale)
print('    ' + ''.join(['{x:>{xscale}}'.format(x=x, xscale=xscale) for x in xs[1:]]))
```

Output:

```
y
 19|                   *
 18|
 17|
 16|
 15|
 14|
 13|
 12|              *
 11|
 10|
  9|
  8|
  7|         *
  6|
  5|
  4|    *
  3|*
  2|
  1|
  0|
   L_________________________
        1    2    3    4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will consider this as an alternate way for graphing the equation. Thank You again and Merry Christmas!!!!!